# Django: LogoutView doesn’t log out - still logged in

Tags: python, django

I have the `url.py` with:

```
url(r'^logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
```

and the `views.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class LogoutView(RedirectView):
    permanent = False
    url = reverse_lazy('login')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logout(request)
        return super(LogoutView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I use the link `<a href="{% url 'logout' %} ">Logout</a>` in my template.

But if I try to logout myself, it doesn't work and I also don't get an error message.

I tried also:

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
```

But I can still access to all pages. I use class-based views and use `@method_decorator(login_required)`.

I use for the login the django module `django-ldap-auth`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `permanent` to `permanent = False`. If you're using Django 1.9+ you can remove the line entirely because it defaults to `False`.

Otherwise, the browser will remember the redirect to the `login` view without making the request to the logout url, so you'll remain logged in.

Your function-based view is returning a redirect to the relative url 'login' at the moment (e.g. `/logout/` to `/logout/login`. You can either hardcode the url, reverse the url, or use the `redirect` shortcut which reverses the url for you:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('login'))
return redirect('login')
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but it still doesn't work yet.

Comment: Your browser could be caching the redirect from before you made the change. Add some printing/logging to make sure that the view is actually being called.

Comment: Your right, Django doesn't call the get function of LogoutView. Do you have a idea why not? My link is ``<a href="{% url 'logout' %} ">Logout</a>``

Comment: It sounds like your browser might have cached the permanent redirect from before. Try a different browser, or clearing your cache.

Answer (score 1):

You've imported the wrong `logout`. That's a view - the thing you import to call within your view is `from django.contrib.auth import logout`.